# Aligning annotations in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to align two annotations.  I want the label located at the midpoint of the bar connecting the two arrows. I'm hoping there is a way of specifying a transform that would allow me to use similar units when specifying the arrows and the label.  Any help is appreciated!! [image]

Using the following code, if I adjust `offset` I can eventually produce acceptable results (as long as I don't change settings such as the size of the figure).

I've also tried specifying `'axes points'` for `xycoords` and `textcoords`, thinking that `armA` and `armB` are in points.

```
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)
f.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
offset = -0.05

# create the arrow annotation
ann = ax.annotate("", (0.6, -0.1), xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'), 
                  xytext=(.8, -0.1), textcoords=('data', 'axes fraction'),
                  arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->",
                  connectionstyle="bar,armA=-20,armB=-20,angle=0,fraction=0.0"))

# add a label to the center of the bar
ann_label = ax.annotate('foo', (.7, -0.1+offset),
                        xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'), 
                        bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', fc='white'), 
                        ha='center', va = 'center')
```

Comment: Mmm... looks like everything apart from the connection lines is being defined in axes coordinates, and the connection lines are stuck in figure coordinates. I'm not sure there is a simple way around this. Having a look at the source may help https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/patches.py

Comment: I actually was looking for a way to align my annotations to the center of the bars and your code helped me to do it. Thanks!